# The flush method of OutputStream does nothing?

Tags: java, io, outputstream

From [`OutputStream.flush()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/OutputStream.html#flush%28%29) docs.

Why does it state here in the doc that the *flush method of `OutputStream` does nothing* after explaining that it actually does something? Very confusing.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`OutputStream` is an abstract class to be derived from. Subclasses will provide their own implementation *if necessary*. Otherwise the default behaviour is to do nothing.

e.g. see the code for [ObjectOutputStream.flush()](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.java#ObjectOutputStream.BlockDataOutputStream.flush%28%29)

Comment: Resonable. But still a strange formulationin the documentation.

Comment: The reason it is in the documentation is that since the method itself is not abstract, developers who are implementing concrete instances of this class need to know what the base class does.  I agree that for consumers of the interface, it is confusing.

Answer (score 2):

`OutputStream` is an abstract class.
The deriving instance has to override that, if it needs a flush.
For example the `BufferedOutputStream`.
Streams that have no buffer may not need to override `flush()`.

Comment: Doesn't have to. It can choose not to

Comment: Like all abstract classed can choose, too implement or not.

Comment: But you've said above, the deriving instance *has to*. That's the bit that I disagree with!

Comment: [`public abstract void write(int b)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/OutputStream.html#write%28int%29) Seems to be the only method of `OutputStream` that is *not* implemented.  All the others have default implementations (even if they do nothing).

Answer (score 0):

The first part of the text is describing the general contract of `flush`.  Classes which extend `OutputStream` are expected to adhere to this contract.

`OutputStream` is an abstract class, but a default implementation of `flush` is provided.  As described, the implementation does nothing.